# How to detect Roads from satellite images and get the outline using opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

**Hey guys, I am trying to detect roads from satellite images.
After identifying the roads am getting the co-ordinates like roads coordinates and building coordinates.**

The code which i tried to extract roads from satellite images.

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjAcE.png)

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from PIL import Image
import operator
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd




#reading image directly from current working directly
build_image = cv2.imread("avilla_san_marcos_gilbert,az.png")

#Doing MeanShift Filtering
#shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 21, 51)

#GrayScale Conversion
build_gray = cv2.cvtColor(build_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#OTSU Thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(build_gray, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cv2.imshow("OTSU Thresholded Image",thresh)
cv2.imwrite("OTSU_1 image.jpg",thresh)        

#Checking Coordinates of White Pixels
build_white =  np.argwhere(thresh == 255)


#Creating an array
build_data= np.array(build_white)
np.savetxt('build_coords.csv', build_data,delimiter=",")



#Checking Coordinates of White Pixels
road_white =  np.argwhere(thresh == 0)

#Creating an array
road_data = np.array(road_white)

print(road_data)

#Saving vector of roads in a csv file
np.savetxt('road_coords.csv', road_data,delimiter=",")
```

[Output image is plotted based on csv of  Road pixel Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2PCf.jpg)

**I have a problem with the output image obtained. It has detected trees i have to eliminate it by obtaining the pixel coordinates of tree.
So From that output image i have to extract the layout of the roads alone.Please try to help me out guys. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have exactly the same :)